# Make git reset restage deleted files

Tags: git

Let's say I deleted `fileA` in commit `abc123`. Then, when I `git reset`, the output of `git diff` shows that `fileA` was deleted. `fileA` is no longer in my working directory, so I can't re-add it.

The default for `git reset` is `git reset --mixed`. This is described in `man git-reset` as:

> Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are
>   preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been
>   updated.

What's an elegant solution. One workaround is to checkout the later commit that contains the file, copy the file, and then checkout `abc123` and add it again.

**SOLUTION**:

Two solutions below are correct. One shows how to recover the file if you checkout the commit at which it was deleted, and you simply run `git checkout fileA`. The other shows how to recover the file in the present commit that's later that the commit at which `fileA` was deleted. You run `git checkout abc123~ -- file A` (The `--` ensures that the checkout command know that we are trying to roll back a file and not change branches).

Comment: you can use `git stash` to temporarily keep the changes in your staging area while resetting

Comment: I edited my question. Your comment is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what happened:

- You checked out commit `abc123` which contains `fileA`.
- You typed `git rm fileA`.
- You typed `git reset`.

And now you see something like this:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    fileA
#
```

and you can't use `git add` to get `fileA` back because it's not on the filesystem anymore.

To recover `fileA`, type: `git checkout fileA`.

You could also use `git reset --hard` if you don't have any other changes you care about in your index or working tree.

Answer (score 1):

`git reset --hard` will reset the index AND the working tree, which will restore deleted files.  If you simply want to re-add a single file that you deleted that you know exists on the current head, you can do so with:

```
git checkout HEAD -- fileA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout an individual file from a specific version:

```
git checkout abc123~ -- fileA
```

This would checkout the version of `fileA` as it existed in the commit 
immediately preceding commit `abc123` where it was removed, thanks to the tilde 
(`~`) after the commit ID.  This modifies the index along with the working 
tree, so it is as if the file was added as well.  If that isn't desired you can 
use `git rm --cached fileA` to remove the file from the index while leaving it 
in the working copy.

Comment: What if `fileA` was modified during the `abc123` commit? Would those modifications be lost when we checkout the file from the previous commit? What if `fileA` was added during commit `abc123`?

Comment: The question stated that the file was removed in the `abc123` commit. If the file was modified (or created) after the preceding commit those changes would indeed be lost. If the file was added to git at some point you may be able to recover it using `git fsck --lost-found` to recover unreferenced blobs into `.git/lost-found/other` but that may yield many files with unhelpful names, you'll need to figure out which file it is.